# Excel issue, kind of like compounding interest, but it isn't

Tags: excel

I am trying to take amounts of an investment with a set interest rate, track the accruing interest, then once the interest earned equals a set amount, add it to the sheet in another column so it will start to earn interest as well... I am trying to use this formula, but I can't find a command where I can take the value from another cell (not the one that the IF statement will be true) and copy it to a completely different one. =IF(G25>0.05,"***VALUE=A4***",SUM(C:C)+G25)
Any help is greatly appreciated
[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0K0x.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but it sounds like instead of `"VALUE=A4"` you just want `A4`? If not, please clarify more.

Comment: I tried a LOT of different commands... I want to copy the value (not formula) of G25 to A4